# When is it OK to ask my unanswered question on a more specific SE site?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, site-crossover

I asked a question on StackOverflow. It has not been answered for some time.

I realized that although SO is completely appropriate, there is another SE site which is more specific to my question. Is it allowed to ask this same question there? Is it frowned upon?

Comment: Cross-posting of questions is typically frowned upon.  Which question is it?

Comment: If you're able to delete your question (meaning you don't have any upvoted answers) then go ahead and delete it and post it on the more appropriate site.

Comment: Or use a bounty. Mm, coconut.